# How to delay, in .js, the next PHP call until a prior PHP call have returned with an answer?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, callback

My internet service provider just reduced the number of parallel php calls to 10, and that kills my .js

I'm a .js novice, but I have been setting this site up with copy-paste code from a friend. It have worked well for our small community, until the resent changes by our service provider. Now I have to fix it, and I need some help.

The .js is here: https://snapseatlas.dk/snapseatlas070.js, The main page is: https://snapseatlas.dk/index_hold.html

The key section to the problem is this:

```
// ** Define some plant layers

// Slaaen
var layerSlaaen = L.geoJson(null,{
    onEachFeature: popPlantenavn,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng, {icon: pinSpurp});}
});
var urlbbox = 'php070/data.php?bbox='+bbox+'&species=Prunus spinosa';
$.getJSON(urlbbox, function (datab) {layerSlaaen.addData(datab)});

// Pors
var layerPors = L.geoJson(null,{
    onEachFeature: popPlantenavn,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng, {icon: pinPgreen});}
});
var urlbbox = 'php070/data.php?bbox='+bbox+'&species=Myrica gale';
$.getJSON(urlbbox, function (datab) {layerPors.addData(datab)});

// Ene
var layerEne = L.geoJson(null,{
    onEachFeature: popPlantenavn,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng, {icon: pinEblue});}
});
var urlbbox = 'php070/data.php?bbox='+bbox+'&species=Juniperus';
$.getJSON(urlbbox, function (datab) {layerEne.addData(datab)});
```

It goes on, defining about 20 plants, but I only show 3 here.

As the code have been working, until now, it sends these 20 php recuests to the php script, that in turn ask the sql server for data.
The new limit of 10 php calls at the time result in the later half of the calls returning error.

[image]

How do I change this .js so all 20 plants gets defined and filled with data?

My initial idea was to put a 1 sec wait between each cal. But wait() doesn't seem to exist in .js, and it would make the page very slow when loading.

I have also been looking into Callback, Promises and Async/Await structures. But I cant really get my head around them - though they seem to be the solution.

Comment: Can't you just define an API in your server-side code that allows passing 20 plants at once, and responds with an array of results? That way you'll have to make only a single call, and it's way more efficient.

Comment: To use `async`/`await`, put the entire data loading code in `(async () => { … })();` (if it isn't already in a `function` - then just mark that as `async`) and place an `await` in front of each `$.getJSON(…)` call. They already return promises that you can wait for.

Comment: @Bergi (ad. 1) Thanks - That is a good thought. The map allow the user to show/hide the plants individually, so I would like to be able to call each plant separately.

Comment: @Bergi (ad. 2) Thanks - I'll try to make that work.

Comment: You could still allow the user to show/hide plants individually, it just removes/adds them from the array of values sent to the server. Or if you want to load one additional plant, that's a server call with a single-element array.

Comment: Whenever the user pan or zoom the map, the data should be updated, because other users may be adding plants at the same time. So assuming the user turned Apples and Oranges on, then on each pan/zoom we should re-fresh the data on Apples and Oranges only, and within the 'bbox' only (i.e. within current map view). The database holds +30.000 plants, so just getting everything, all the time, seems like an expensive stretegy.

Comment: I didn't say you should get all 30000 plants, but that you should load Apples and Oranges together in a single request.